# In Python, 'Inspecting' callable objects that aren't strictly [functions?]

Tags: python

I've found [a number](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python%20inspect.getfullargspec) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228664/how-to-check-which-arguments-a-function-method-takes/23228684#23228684) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847936/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-arguments-of-a-python-function/41188411#41188411) dealing with determining the parameters/arguments needed for functions* in python.  Python has a number of callable objects (using `callable`) that will return a value for which inspect.getfullargspec returns an error (inspect.Signature seems less reliable by my informal testing?).

For example:

`inspect.getfullargspec(max)`
Returns an Error:
`TypeError: unsupported callable`

Is there an alternative to inspect that will work for otherwise "unsupported callable" [functions/objects?]

Looking at a number of builtin callable objects it seems like many are in the "unsupported" category, i can only guess at objects in other modules/libraries.

*I may be mincing my terms here, apologies - any way to determine specifically which is which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CPython, builtin functions are implemented in C, and thus have many quirks. This is one of them. Taking some examples from [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/#history-of-positional-only-parameter-semantics-in-python):

> In current versions of Python, many CPython "builtin" and standard
>   library functions only accept positional-only parameters. The
>   resulting semantics can be easily observed by calling one of these
>   functions using keyword arguments:

```
>>> help(pow)
...
pow(x, y, z=None, /)
...

>>> pow(x=5, y=3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: pow() takes no keyword arguments
```

> `pow()` expresses that its parameters are positional-only via the / marker.
>   However, this is only a documentation convention; Python developers
>   cannot use this syntax in code.
>
> There are functions with other interesting semantics:
>
> - `range()`, an overloaded function, accepts an optional parameter to the
>     left of its required parameter.
> - `dict()`, whose mapping/iterator
>     parameter is optional and semantically must be positional-only. Any
>     externally visible name for this parameter would occlude that name
>     going into the **kwarg keyword variadic parameter dict.

Currently (while the PEP is not implemented) Python has no official way to express these unusual semantics such as positional only arguments.